# How do I add fields to the django_rest_auth response object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am extending the default django rest auth Login class in order to add 2 fields to the response object; the user's subscription and email addresses.

```py
REST_AUTH = {
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'dj_rest_auth.serializers.LoginSerializer',
}
```

```py
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import LoginSerializer

class CustomLoginSerializer(LoginSerializer):
    subscription = SubscriptionSerializer(read_only=True)
    email_addresses = EmailAddressSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # fields = ['pk', 'username', 'email']
        fields = ['pk', 'username', 'email', 'subscription', 'email_addresses']
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        print('instance: ' + instance)
        data = super(CustomLoginSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data['subscription'] = instance.user.subscription
        data['email_addresses'] = instance.user.email_addresses.all()
        data['lol'] = 'lmao'
        return data
```

This is the response object. Note the added fields aren't present.

```js
{
    "access": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNzA2NTYxNjQyLCJpYXQiOjE3MDY0NzUyNDIsImp0aSI6ImFhYTg5OTNlODQ5MTRjODJhOGRjNGU3MDE5MjE4YzNkIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6NH0.1l7RtT8G1qL6Tq5RVzLe5ceu_mnNVJV8oW64An_-hHk",
    "refresh": "",
    "user": {
        "pk": 4,
        "username": "user102",
        "email": "user102@email.com",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": ""
    }
}
```

Since overriding the `to_representation` method doesn't seem to work, how do I add related fields to the response object?

Comment: How do you override the serializer for LoginView?

Comment: if you are overriding the login serializer then you may need to update the `LOGIN_SERIALIZER` path to configuration in your `settings.py` as shown in the documentation https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration

Comment: I updated the post to include settings.py. I've already set the LoginSerializer class.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here, was to override `'JWT_SERIALIZER': 'api.serializers.CustomJWTSerializer'` and add the updated User serializer.